# “Concatenate layer” problem when doing GRAD-CAM. How to overcome this in my custom functional model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am having problems with grad-cam. I would be grateful if anyone could help. my codes are here

https://www.kaggle.com/mervearmagan/gradcamproblem

Sorry, I couldn't fix the error I got

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_1: expected
> shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), found shape=(512, 512, 3)

```
img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = IMG_SHAPE)
gender = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(input_shape = IMG_SHAPE, include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')

cnn_vec=base_model(img)
cnn_vec = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_vec)
cnn_vec = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20)(cnn_vec)
gender_vec = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation = 'relu')(gender)

features = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([cnn_vec,gender_vec])

dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation = 'relu')(features)
dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(dense_layer)
dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation = 'relu')(dense_layer)
dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(dense_layer)
dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation = 'relu')(dense_layer)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(dense_layer)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[img,gender],outputs=output_layer`

def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names):
        last_conv_layer = model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name)
        last_conv_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(model.inputs, last_conv_layer.output)
        
        classifier_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=last_conv_layer.output.shape)
        #classifier_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=last_conv_layer.output.shape[1:])
        x = classifier_input
        for layer_name in classifier_layer_names:
            x = model.get_layer(layer_name)(x)
        classifier_model = tf.keras.Model(classifier_input, x)
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            last_conv_layer_output =last_conv_layer_model(img_array)
             #last_conv_layer_model(img_array)
            tape.watch(last_conv_layer_output)
            
            preds = classifier_model(last_conv_layer_output)
            top_pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
            top_class_channel = preds[:, top_pred_index]
            
        grads = tape.gradient(top_class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)
        pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))
        
        last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output.numpy()[0]
        pooled_grads = pooled_grads.numpy()
        for i in range(pooled_grads.shape[-1]):
            last_conv_layer_output[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads[i]
        
        heatmap = np.mean(last_conv_layer_output, axis=-1)
        heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0) / np.max(heatmap)
        return heatmap
    
last_conv_layer_name = 'global_average_pooling2d'
classifier_layer_names = ['dense_4']
img = get_input('4360.png' ) 
inputgender=tf.ones((1,1))
image=tf.reshape(img,(1,512,512,3))
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap([image,inputgender], model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the model remember to test the model using inputs in form:

```
model([tf.ones((1,512,512,3)),tf.ones((1,1))])
```

...in case where you input one image and one gender to the network. The first "1" in the tensors means the first "batch" of samples, and so on. That kind of input should give as a result like:

[image]

...which looks like OK at this stage. Go through your code and check this "stage" first and then go forward in your program.

Comment: You are right, but when I give 2 entries, I get the 1st (512,512,3) entries. How do I convert image to tf.ones ((1,512,512,3)) format?
Do I need to reshape the 1st entry? how can I do that?

I shared the codes. Can you actually look? can you help with the code?

thanks.

Comment: Use tf.reshape ... I'll add an example as another answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. you made me very happy. but the problem was not solved, I am facing a new problem. I add the problem in detail below.
Thank you very, very much

Answer (score 0):

This is a handy way to covert image in numpy array format to a tensor having a extra dimension in it, to be compatible with the neural network input:

```
#Advice how to convert image to format of tensor...
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#Download image...and suppose it has size 512x512,3...e.g. using PIL or whatever suitable library...
#image = Image.open('smile_or_not.png')

#Convert the image to numpy...here we simulate it because no real image was loaded...
image_np=np.random.rand(512,512,3)

#Let's see its shape...
print("Size of input image:",image_np.shape)

#And convert it to a tensor of shape (1,height,widht,3)
in_tensor_format=tf.reshape(image_np,(1,512,512,3))

print("...has a shape of: ", in_tensor_format.shape, "...when converted to tensor")
```

Comment: I edited the codes as above. The error code has changed. I get this error. I get similar errors when I type different layers instead of dense_1. `ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2080 but received input with shape (1, 2048)`